# Java Selenium - Is it possible to take a screenshot if something fails in @AfterMethod?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

Generally, I would like to take a screenshot if something fails in @AfterMethod, before closing the browser, etc.

I run Test and it passes, but it changes some data, and in @AfterMethod this data is restored to a basic state, but sometimes it fails and stack sometimes is not enough to figure out what exactly caused the problem. Because of the above, I would like (if it is possible) to take a screenshot if @AfterMethod fails.

By "something fails in @AfterMethod" I mean e.g. encountering an exception.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "if @AfterMethod fail"? You mean if an exception is encountered, or something else?

Comment: Well, would it be acceptable to wrap the current code of the function in a `try` block, then telling it to take a screenshot in a `catch`?

Comment: @C.Peck Thank you! Didn't thought about it, but tested it and works as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every fail errors comes from AssertionError Exception if you want to take a screenshot you should catch the AssertionError

how? make try catch block like this

```
try{
 Assert.assertTrue(false) // this throws thread into the catch block
}catch(AssertionError error){
   driver.takeSreenshot() // I don't remember method name

  //and in the end throw again to fail it in reality
  throw error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Did same as C.Peck commented and worked well.